# Android imageview image quality matter?

Tags: android, imageview

I am writing a Android app which need to display some high quality picture(took from professional DSLR). The problem is it can't be display from gallery.

I choose a photo in Gallery first. The target picture is 2464*1632 JPEG, roughly 4.5M;

Then I just need to compress it to 800*600 and display it in imageview:

```
image.setImageBitmap(this.bmp);
```

Thing is that I have tested other image I downloaded form internet(really low quality), and it works without any problem. Can anybody tell me why it can't be displayed? I will be really appericiated

Comment: What about it isn't working? If you're getting an error, can you post that?

Comment: It just crushed. I have no idea why it crush. Other pictures are fine but when I chose the one my client gave to me it just crushed when I selected the picture from gallery.

Comment: What do you mean by 'crushed'?

Comment: like some unexpected error occur have to shut down the app

Comment: What's the logcat of that exception? Remove that catch (Exception ex) and actually read the stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

Large images are tricky to handle due to limited memory. You have several choices:

- Use a WebView (this allows you to have pinch and zoom functionality to make use of those extra pixels
- Decode the image down to the size of the display and then put it in an ImageView using BitmapOpts http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html and changing `inSampleSize`. It seems you may be having difficulty with that, so consider using [createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) which just needs the dest width and height.

Comment: 1) WebView has even worse image quality constraints and is generally very finicky about quality - it will gladly degrade your image under memory pressure and you have no way of stopping or detecting it
2) `createScaledBitmap` takes a source bitmap, not a stream. He has to use BitmapFactory and nothing in there auto-detects the sample size.

Comment: There is nothing preventing him from loading the file into a Bitmap and then using `createScaledBitmap` (although you're effectively copying here). Using a `WebView` can make the most use of the high resolution of the image, which may be more desirable than having a scaled down version of the image. Finally, you CAN calculate the correct sample size to pass into `BitmapFactory` such that the image will be at the correct size. All of these are valid options whether you like it or not.

Comment: You *will not* make use of the high resolution with WebView. Pinch-to-zoom *will not* re-decode regions of the image and will instead give you a blurry mess. Try it.

What's stopping him from loading the file to a Bitmap is the size - 4.5 megapixels * 4 bytes/pixel = 18M for this one object. There are devices out there with 16M heaps. Even if they are to be ignored, this leaves little breathing room for the rest of his app.

He *is* calculating the correct `inSampleSize`. If you can see something wrong with that, point it out, please; completely dismissing the code he's submitted doesn't help.

Comment: Yea I think it is about size of the picture, to be honest I don't think a tablet should handle this... Even using Photoshop processing such image will be a bit lag too... I found this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html but I don't quiet understand how it works